# window.open(url, target) doesn't activate a tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.open

This simple code:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com', 'my-tab')">open google</button>
```

Works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox (latest v75) it opens always, but activates a new tab only the first time.

#### Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nmp049Lu/1/

#### Steps to reproduce

1. click the button, a new tab with google in it should be opened and active
2. do not close the newly opened tab, but go back to the live demo tab
3. click the button again

#### Expected behavior

The same tab as in step 2 gets opened and activated (gets visible)

#### Actual behavior

The same tab as in step 2 gets opened **but not activated (doesn't get visible)**

Is this a bug in Firefox or I'm missing something?

Comment: It's working fine for me in firefox also.

Comment: @rzwnahmd I tested in Windows and Linux, the same result. Are you sure you're following the steps to reproduce?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the steps. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com', 'my-tab').focus()">open google</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @rzwnahmd